# Function call with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Is it possible to construct function call (inside function template) with variable number of arguments, depending on number of template arguments? Something like:

```
void f(int i) {}
void f(int i1, int i2){}
void f(int i1, int i2, int i3){}
...

template<typename... T>
void caller() {
   f(/* sizeof...(T) number of arguments; of form T_i::value */);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; the template parameter pack `T` may expanded the same way as a function parameter pack:

```
template<typename... T>
caller() {
   f(T::value...);
}
```